# SQL count Date type from column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a few tables in the SQL developer and I have a column containing dates like in the picture. What I want to do is count the column elements from January 2021, for example. [reqd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KTIb.png)

Comment: "YYYY/MM/DD" is not a *type*.  `date` is a time.  `varchar2` is a type.  And there are many others.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the types would help.

Comment: What?  Do not understand.  Please edit the question